# Unit testing Ruby fork

Tags: ruby, unit-testing

I wanted to create a Pull Request to the [Ruby](https://github.com/ruby/ruby) repo. In order to do that, I forked the Ruby repo on my Github account and downloaded the fork to my computer. I then edited one class and now I wanted to run unit tests to see if the added assertions pass.

How can I run these unit tests with this forked version of Ruby? If I just run `ruby test/matrix/test_matrix.rb` it runs the tests with the Ruby version I have installed in RVM (2.1.2). As a result, my newly created assertions fail since the unit tests are not run against the modified code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you've only modified the standard library without any C code changes, try adding the `lib/` directory to the load-path variable explicitly before running the tests.

```
ruby -I lib/ test/matrix/test_matrix.rb
```